# How to use laravel respose json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

**in my controller**

```
return view('admin.venue', ['cityList' => City::all()->toJson() ]);
```

and also i have tried it with

**in my view**

```
var allCities =  {{$cityList}};
```

and also i have tried

```
var allCities = JSON.parse({{$cityList}})
and
var allCities = JSON.parse('{{$cityList}}')
```

but it reply below error , i think the problem is about double quot. what is the correct way to use laravel json response in javascript

> SyntaxError: invalid property id
>
> var allCities = 
>   [{&-quot;id":1,&-quot;name":"cityname&-quot;,&-quot;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`:

```
var allCities =  {!! $cityList !!};
```

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data